# ZFC: Sets are classes - notational question

Tags: set-theory

I am following some [lecture notes](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/99015/mod_resource/content/1/320lecturenotes.pdf) I found online to study axiomatic set theory, more precisely ZFC. The lectures have also been recorded and can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3chtyYpjxAo&list=PLuiPz6iU5SQ_3Gubdqa1JHBvM0GBFcIV0&index=1).

The first lecture is mostly an introduction and mentions that we use first-order logic to derive sentences, which as far as I understand are mathematical statements formed according to some specific rules (syntax) that are either true or false. We also give the sentences some meaning, e.g. we think of variables as sets and $\in$ is thought of as membership. To tell whether a sentence is true we reduce it to simpler sentences, but at some point we simply stop and assume that certain sentences are true and these are our axioms. Again to give this some meaning, we also pretend there is a universe of sets and these axioms can be interpreted as statements about this universe of sets that we intuitivelky believe to be true.

Even though I have not studied logic this seems to make sense to me. In the second lecture classes are informally defined as collections of sets. I understand why classes might be useful and I also understand that with this informal definition they might not be sets. This means we cannot directly talk about them in our axiomatic system. However, we would still like to be able to do so. The trick is to define classes in terms of a property of sets, i.e. a formula with one free variable. So we can define a class as

$\{x: \varphi(x)\}$ where $\varphi(x)$ is a formula with the free variable $x$.

We can then deal with classes by using the formulas defining them, e.g. if $c$ and $D$ are defined by the formulas $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, then we formally state $C=D$ by saying $\forall x (\varphi(x) \iff \psi(x))$. We also allow formulas with multiple free variables and call the additional variables parameters, which means they are fixed sets.

So far so good. Next, the lecture notes mention the following:

[image]

Again, I think it's clear that we can form the class defined by the formula $y \in x$ and intuitively a collection of all members of the set $x$ should be the set $x$. However, the notation $x = \{y : y \in x\}$ confuses me.

Is this an abuse of notation? We basically just introduce a shorthand notation for the class $\{y : y \in x\}$ and we call this $x$ as well, right? This is because we think of this class as the set $x$ even though as mentioned earlier classes do not make any sense in our axiomatic system. So to state it differently this is an informal definition that says that we will call this class $x$ similar to what we do in "everyday" mathematics.

I would appreciate if anyone could clarify this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read that passage carefully you will see that it says *given a set $x$...*.

Once the set $x$ is given, it makes sense to write a mathematical sentence about the set $x$, expressed in the language of set theory, perhaps using set builder notation (such as $\{y \mid y \in x\}$). And it also makes sense to discuss the truth or falsity of that sentence.

Thus, the sentence $x = \{y \mid y \in x\}$ makes perfect sense. In more common language it says *the set $x$ is equal to the set of all $y$ such that $y \in x$*.

One thing that ought to become clear pretty soon in your lecture notes (or in any book/course on set theory) is that axioms of ZFC are carefully formulated in such a way that lets you use set builder notation to express those sets whose existence is being postulated by the axioms. In particular this is true of the [axiom scheme of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#3._Axiom_schema_of_specification_(also_called_the_axiom_schema_of_separation_or_of_restricted_comprehension)), which let's you use the given set $x$ to express a new set $\{y \mid y \in x\}$, although as it turns out this "new" set is equal to $x$ itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think what I don't understand is this: Above we basically introduce some notation for classes and we say that showing two classes are equal amounts to equivalence of the formulas used to define them. But if we write $x = \{y: y \in x\}$, then the left-hand side is a set and the right hand side is a class defined by the formula $y \in x$. I guess I don't understand why this is even meaningful. I thought we write everything in first-order logic or if we don't as in the case of classes it is clear what this means in first-order logic.

Comment: As I said in my last paragraph, the axiom scheme of specification says that the right hand side is indeed a set, and so that equation is meaningful.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But the lecture notes bring this up before introducing a single axiom. Maybe this is why I am so confused. Once we know the right-hand side is a set, we know the statement is true by the axiom of extensionality, correct? Is this the way to think about it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for steering me into the right direction.

Comment: I have given this another thought and I think it's actually even simpler. We want to prove that sets are classes: Let $x$ be a set. First $\{x: y \in x\}$ is a class defined by the formulas $y \in x$. Showing that this class is a set amounts to proving $\exists z \forall y (y \in z \iff y \in x)$. But the existence of such a set $z$ is clear since we assume that $x$ exists and $x$ trivially satisfies $\forall y (y \in x \iff y \in x)$. Once we know this is a set, the Axiom of Extensionality shows that the set $x$ and the set $\{y: y \in x\}$ are the same and we are done.

Comment: *If* classes are part of your axiomatization then your last comment is sound. And in fact there are other axiomatizations of set theory beyond ZFC in which classes are indeed axiomatized, such as [von Neumann - Gödel - Bernays set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann–Bernays–Gödel_set_theory). *But* classes are not axiomatized in ZFC. Nonetheless the ZFC axioms themselves assert the existence of sets that one needs for most ordinary mathematical use, such as the set $\{y \mid y \in x\}$ that you ask about in your post.

Comment: Well, as far as my understanding goes classes are not part of ZFC and we just indirectly talk about them using the formulas that define them, right? So translated into the first-order language saying that a class with the formula $y \in x$ exists means $\exists z \forall y (y \in z \iff y \in x)$, right? Here $y$ is a free variable and $x$ is a parameter, so this is a formula of the form $\varphi(y,x)$. So even though we cannot directly talk about classes inside ZFC we can show that a set with the property $y \in x$ exists. Or am I going completely wrong here?

Comment: I think all I am saying is that we do not need the Axiom of Specification in this particular case because the existence of the class in question defined by $y∈x$ is already an assumption. for more complicated properties this is different and as you said the Axiom of Soecification establishes the existence of sets we might want to use as long as we draw the elements from some other set that we know exists.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what is happening in your case: we are drawing the elements from some other set that we know exists, namely the set $x$; hence, the set $\{y \mid y \in x\}$ exists. And having established the existence of that set, we are then proving that it is equal to $x$. I'll emphasize that I'm only addressing the formal issue of existence of the set $\{y \mid y \in x\}$ as requested in our original post. Outside of that formal issue, everything else you are saying seems informally just fine to me.

Comment: Yes, it of course amounts to the same thing. The Axiom of Specification in this case says $\forall x \exists z \forall y (y \in z \iff y \in x \wedge y \in x)$. Of course $y \in x \wedge y \in x$ is just $y \in x)$.